# android listview less items fill screen

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I've custom list view layout. The items in list are going to be 5 or more. If more than say, 5-10 items are there in list, it looks good.

But if there are say only 5 items, then blank space appears below list on devices larger in height. This does not look good.

following is my list row layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_update_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="#b73a3e"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_update_excerpt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_update_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_uid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_update_title"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="some" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_uid"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_update_excerpt"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And listview -

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tag_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tagline"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_updates"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="0px"
            android:overScrollMode="never" >
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I desire is, if height of device is larger then I want list to take complete height by scaling height of each row in way that it should display all items w/o scroll. If items are more then scroll should appear. How can I set this up?

---

**Update**

I can opt-in for a solution where I'd check how many items are going to be there in list before and if they are less than 5-6, I'd choose a different layout consisting of LinearLayout or something that would fill up the blank space. But I can't figure out the structure I need to choose for such `LinearLayout`. Should I choose 5-6 LinearLayout below one another or a single with iteration?

Comment: Are you meaning it doesn't retain the background color you've chosen and instead the remaining area of the list is the theme color?

Comment: Instead of background color, I prefer to fit those fewer items with device height filling whole height. If items are more then it should display normally.

Comment: Yes, but you desire that because it doesn't look good. There's a solution that would allow the empty list area to have the same background as the rest of the view and therefore looking good. The issue I see with your idea is inconsistencies between uses. If I use the app with one item it's needlessly stretched, if I have 10 it looks like I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Well,in my view if I need to implement such a function,I'll do like below:

- check if there exist blank you dont
  want(blankHeight=(ListViewHeight-count*rowHeight)>0)
- heightToPlus = blankHeight/count
- then you can set the height of each row to rowHeight+heightToPlus

every height can be get by getHeight and also can be set by setHeight,they're method of view.
So i think it not hard to implement...